# Quickest CRUD application for a two tables schema (Oracle 11g) in Java?

Tags: java, frameworks, crud

I have two tables, each with about 10 columns. I need to develop a CRUD web application that can search, read, update, create or delete records from this table. The update is limited to two fields - status & a date field.

I was wondering what is the quickest way of achieving this CRUD application. We use java / Oracle Application Server 10g (I know, I know!!), so I guess the CRUD application needs to be in java. Also because it is an internal app I don't really need it to be super robust and fancy and all. Just a basic functionality that works with a web UI. We use vanilla servlets / jsp now.

TL;DR I guess (not sure) my question is about which framework I can use to achieve FASTEST results for a CRUD application for a 2 table schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[openxava](http://openxava.org/en)

**Others**

- Spring Roo
- [JBOSS Forge](http://forge.jboss.org/)

Comment: openxava really looks fantastic. I will play with it tomorrow, I hope it lives up to what I expect out of it. Thanks, Pangea!

Comment: also take a look at grails.  it's groovy which is java-ish, so i'm not sure if it meets your criteria or not.

Comment: Grails is something I thought would work and wanted to explore. So please clarify - if I write / generate code using grails, can I just deploy it on my existing java/JEE application as is? I cannot install anything separately or make changes to core components of the application.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way for Java/CRUD scaffolding from an existing database 
is probably the Telosys Tools code generator 
( see https://sites.google.com/site/telosystools/ )
 ( and tutorials  https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/ )

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jboss forge creating a simple crud application 
Steps to create a simple crud application with JSF CDI and Hibernate are listed [here](http://nueron.blogspot.in/2013/08/jboss-forge-for-headstart-in-web.html)